# Generating Function for Recurrence Relation in 2 Variable

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have a recurrence relation with 2 variables similar to 
$$
F(n,m) = n\cdot F(n-1,m) + (n-m)\cdot F(n-1,m-1)
$$
I want to know the steps required to get the generating Function for such recurences.
I have gone through a similar post : [Solving recurrence relation in 2 variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206158/solving-recurrence-relation-in-2-variables) 
. But how do I solve when there is a multiplication as in the above equations ?

Comment: Related to [OEIS A078341](https://oeis.org/A078341), which does not give a generating function.

Comment: @Henry The recurrence relation that I am trying to solve is actually more complex than the one mentioned in my question. Which is why I am looking for the steps I can take to solve similar questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strategy is to look for the generating function
$$
G(x,y)=\sum_{n,m}F(n,m)x^ny^m.
$$ 
To do so:

- Multiply by $x^ny^m$ each term in the identity, getting
  $$
  F(n,m)x^ny^m = n\cdot F(n-1,m) x^ny^m+ (n-m)\cdot F(n-1,m-1)x^ny^m.
  $$
- The LHS terms sum to the generating function
  $G(x,y)$.
- For the first terms on the RHS, use the identity
  $$
  nx^ny^m=\left(x^2\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\right) x^{n-1}y^m.
  $$
- For the second terms on the RHS, use the identity
  $$
  (n-m)x^ny^m=xy\cdot\left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) x^{n-1}y^{m-1}.
  $$
- Deduce that
  $$
  G(x,y)=x^2\cdot\frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial x}+xG(x,y)+x^2y\cdot\frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial x}-xy^2\frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial y}+H(x,y),
  $$
  where $H(x,y)$ is a polynomial correction due to the terms of low degrees in the sums.

Whether this PDE can be solved is another story.

Comment: How would I calculate $H(x,y)$ ?

Comment: Looking at `the terms of low degrees`.