# A recursive divisor function

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, recursion

Question:

**Function definition**:
$$f(1)=1$$
$$f(p)=p$$ where $p$ is a prime, and
$$f(n)=\prod {f(d_n)}$$ where $d_n$ are the divisors of $n$ except $n$ itself.

**End result**:

The end result of the function is when all divisors have been reduced to primes or 1.
Example:$$f(12)=f(2)f(3)f(4)f(6)=f(2)f(3)f(2)f(2)f(3)=f(2)^3f(3)^2=72$$

**Question parts**:

(a) Find a general formula for $f(a^n)$ where $a$ is a prime and $n$ is a natural number.
(b) Find a general formula for $f(a^nb^m)$ (following same notation). [Note: $a$ and $b$ are unique primes. $n$ and $m$, however, may be equal.]

**Attempts at solutions**:

(a) We have solved it. The solution is:
$a^{2^{n-2}}$ if $n≥2$,
$a$ if $n=1$.

(b) As of yet, none of us (me and my colleagues) have come up with a solution. We have solved the special cases
$$f(ab^m)=a^{2^{m-1}} \times b^{(2^{m-2})(m+1)}$$
$$f(a^2b^m)=a^{(2^{m-1})(m+2)} \times b^{(2^{m-2})(m^2+5m+2)/2}$$
$$f(a^3b^m)=a^{(2^{m-1})(m^2+7m+8)/2} \times b^{(2^{m-2})(m^3+12m^2+29m+6)/6}$$
**Update 1**: $f(a^4b^m)$ has been solved as well.
$$f(a^4b^m)=a^{(2^{m-1})(m^3+15m^2+56m+48)/6} \times b^{(2^{m-2})(m^4+22m^3+131m^2+206m+24)/24}$$

An answer to the above questions is needed. A general formula for $f(n)$ is appreciated, along with an explanation.

Comment: are a and b two different primes?

Comment: I apologise, n and m are natural.

Comment: I get the following reccurrency for the exponents of $a$ and $b$:
if $$f(a^n \cdot b^m)=a^{e_1(n,m)}\cdot b^{e_2(n,m)}$$
and $$e(x,y)=(e_1(x,y),e_2(x,y))$$
then
$$e(0,0)=(0,0),\\ e(1,0)=(1,0),\\ e(0,1)=(0,1), \\e(n,m)=2e(n-1,m)+2e(n,m-1)-2e(n-1,m-1)$$

But I don't know how t solve it.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to mathematically approach it either. All my own findings were by looking for patterns.

Comment: I think there is an error in my recurrancy for small n and m (n or m in {0,1,2})

Comment: Some findings of my own:
(1) A term of $2^{m-1}$ is always present in the term with fixed power. $2^{m-2}$ for the variable.
(2) The denominator of the power is the factorial of the fixed power.
(3) The degree of the polynomial is equal to the value of the fixed power.

Comment: The polynomials are 1 and m+1;m+2 and ${m+3\choose2}-2$; ${m+4\choose2}-2$ and ${m+5\choose3}-3(m+3)$; ${m+6\choose3}-3(m+4)$ and ${m+7\choose4}-4{m+5\choose2}+6$

Comment: Indeed. The polynomial of the constant term is $g(m+1)$ of the polynomial of the previous variable power $g(m)$.

Comment: Where did the question come from?

Comment: Err, in all honesty, a friend of mine came up with it when we were bored. This is just one of a few others that we have come up with over the course of some months. Till date, only one has been solved. And this is the first that has been posted on MSE.

Comment: @MainakRoy it is easy to find formulas for fixed n, if they have the structure  $2^{m+k} poly(m):$ calculate the numbers for m=1,2,3,...using the recursive function in my post and from these values calculate the poynomial poly by using the method of succesive differences or solving a system of linear equations,

Comment: @miracle173 That's how I found the other few polynomials, though first by finding fixed n by hand. Your recursive function makes it easier, but this problem still stands :(

Comment: @miracle173 If possible, can you please check the solution function of my friend? I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The function can be defined recursively in the following way.

If $a$ and $b$ are different primes then 
$$f(a^m \cdot b^n)= a^r\cdot b^s \tag{1}$$  so we can use the function $e$ that uses and calculates the exponents of the primes instead of $f$ and $1$ can be written as
$$e(m,n)=(r,s)\tag{2}$$

We have 
$$f(a^m\cdot b^n)=\prod\limits_{i=0,\ldots,m\\ j=0,\ldots,n\\ (i,j)\ne(m,n)} f(a^i\cdot b^j)\tag{3}$$
and therefore
$$e(m,n)=\sum\limits_{i=0,\ldots,m\\ j=0,\ldots,n\\ (i,j)\ne(m,n)} e(i, j)\tag{4}$$

The area of the  praxial rectangle defined by $A(m, n)$ is the area of the praxial rectancle defined by $B$ plus  the area of the praxial rectancle defined by $C$ minus the area of the praxial rectancle defined by $D$.

And similar: The number of grid points in the  praxial rectangle defined by $A(m, n)$ is the number of grid points of the praxial rectancle defined by $B$ plus  the number of grid points of the praxial rectancle defined by $C$ minus the number of grid points of the praxial rectancle defined by $D$.

[image]

So the arguments of $e$ in the sum are all grid points contained in the paraxial rectangle determined by $A=(m,n)$. This rectangle is defined as
$$R(m,n)=\{(i,j),i=0,\ldots,m; j=0\ldots,n\}\tag{5}$$ then

$$e(m,n)=e(A)=\sum\limits_{(u,v)\in R(A)\setminus 
\{A\}}e(u,v)\tag{6}$$
$$= \sum\limits_{(u,v)\in R(B)}e(u,v)+\sum\limits_{(u,v)\in R(C)}e(u,v)-\sum\limits_{(u,v)\in R(D)}e(u,v)\tag{7}$$

But we have

$$e(B)=\sum\limits_{(u,v)\in R(B)\setminus 
\{B\}}e(u,v)\tag{8}$$
if the coordinates of $B$ are larger or equal than $3.$
So in this case we have

$$\sum\limits_{(u,v)\in R(B)}e(u,v)=e(B)+\sum\limits_{(u,v)\in R(B)\setminus 
\{B\}}e(u,v)=e(B)+e(B)\tag{9}$$
and similar holds for the other two sums so we finally get

$$ e(m,n)=2e(m-1,n)+2e(m,n-1)-2e(m-1,n-1), \\ \forall m,n:\; m+n>2, (m,n)\not \in \{(2,1), (1,2)\},m>0, n>0\tag{10}$$

Further we have
    $$e(0,0)=(0,0)\\
e(1,0)=(1,0)\\
e(0,1)=(0,1)\\ 
e(2,0)=(1,0)\\
e(1,1)=(1,1)\\
e(0,2)=(0,1)\\
e(2,1)=(3,2)\\
e(1,2)=(2,3)
\tag{11}$$

and
$$
e(m,0)=2e(m-1,0)\\
e(0,n)=2e(0,n-1) \tag{12}
$$

From $(11)$ and $(12)$ we get

$$e(m,0)=(2^{m-1},0), \forall m>0\\
e(0,n)=(0,2^{n-1}), \forall n>0 \tag{12.1}
$$

But I don't know how to solve this recursion.

Here is the code of the function e in [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/)

```
e[0,0]:[0,0];
e[1,0]:[1,0];
e[0,1]:[0,1];
e[2,0]:[1,0];
e[1,1]:[1,1];
e[0,2]:[0,1];
e[2,1]:[3,2];
e[1,2]:[2,3];
e[m,n]:=if (m=0) then 2*e[m,n-1] else (
    if (n=0) then 2*e[m-1,n] 
    else 2*e[m,n-1]+2*e[m-1,n]-2*e[m-1,n-1]);

/* solution function of Michael */
sol(m,n):=2^(m-2)*if evenp(n) then 
    sum(combination(m+n+2*i-1,2*i)*(-1)^(n/2-i)*combination(n,n/2-i),i,0,n/2)
else
    sum(combination(m+n+2*i,2*i+1)*(-1)^((n-1)/2-i)*combination(n,(n-1)/2-i),i,0,(n-1)/2);
```

From the calculations in [the OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2613617/11206) we see that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
e(1,m)&=&\left(2^{m-1},\right.& \left. 2^{m-2}(m+1)\right) \\
e(2,m)&=&\left(2^{m-1}(m+2),\right.& \left. 2^{m-2}\frac{m^2+5m+2}{2}\right)\\
e(3,m)&=&\left(2^{m-1}\frac{m^2+7m+8}{2},\right.& \left. 2^{m-2}\frac{m^3+12m^2+29m+6}{6}\right)\\  
e(4,m)&=&\left(2^{m-1}\frac{m^3+15m^2+56m+48}{6},\right.& \left. 2^{m-2}\frac{m^4+22m^3+131m^2+206m+24}{24}\right)
\end{eqnarray}$$
Michael [proposed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2615821/11206)
$$s(m,n)=\begin{cases} 
2^{m-2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}-i}{m+n+2i-1 \choose 2i}{n\choose \frac{n}{2}-i} & n\equiv 0 \pmod 2\\
2^{m-2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}-i}{m+n+2i \choose 2i}{n\choose \frac{n-1}{2}-i}& n\equiv 1 \pmod 2
\end{cases} 
$$
This [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/206187/11206) by Ross Milikan says that the solution of

$$F(m,n) = F(m-1,n) + F(m,n-1)\\
F(m,0)=F(0,n)=1 \tag{13}$$
is
$$F(m,n)={{m+n}\choose{m}} \tag{14}$$

If we set $$e(m,n)=2^{m+n}h(m,n)  \tag{15}$$ an substitute this in $(10) then we get

$$ 2^{m+n}g(m,n)=2^{m+n}g(m-1,n)+2^{m+n}g(m,n-1)-2^{m+n-1}g(m-1,n-1)\tag{16}$$
and further
$$ g(m,n)=g(m-1,n)+g(m,n-1)-\frac{1}{2}g(m-1,n-1)\tag{17}$$
and 
$$g(m,0)=(\frac{1}{2},0)\\
g(0,n)=(0,\frac{1}{2})
$$
The solution function $g$ of $(17)$ is smaller than the solution function $F$ of $(13)$
, because we add additionally a negative amount on the right side. So we can conlude that

$$g(m,n)\le{m+n\choose m}\tag{18}$$

and further

$$e(m,n)\le \left(2^{m+n}{m+n\choose m},2^{m+n}{m+n\choose m}\right)\tag{19}$$

So this is an upper bound for $e(m,n)$

Comment: I honestly did not understand what is going on here. Can you please explain?

Comment: @MainakRoy I tagged the formulas. which one is unclear?

Comment: I got what you meant upto the paraxial rectangle. But I can't understand what came after that.

Comment: you still understand (6)?

Comment: No. I understood upto (5) but didn't understand what the $R(A)\{A}$ term meant exactly.

Comment: @MainakRoy A is the point (m,n).  R(A) is the set of grid points in the paraxial rectangle defined by A, \ is the set difference operator and so R(A)\{A} is the set of all points of the paraxial rectangle except A. So in the ascii picture these are the grid points marked as + and B and C and D

Comment: OK. Now I can understand the rest. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The polynomials in the exponent of $b$ can be written
$${m+1\choose1}\\{m+3\choose2}-{2\choose1}\\
{m+5\choose3}-{3\choose1}{m+3\choose1}\\
{m+7\choose4}-{4\choose1}{m+5\choose2}+{4\choose2}$$
The values at $m=0,1,2$ are $1,2^k,2^{k-1}(k+2)$ so I predict the next two polynomials are 
$${m+9\choose5}-{5\choose1}{m+7\choose3}+{5\choose2}{m+5\choose1}\\
{m+11\choose6}-{6\choose1}{m+9\choose4}+{6\choose2}{m+7\choose2}-{6\choose3}$$

The polynomial for $a$ is the polynomial for $b$ coming from $m+1$ and $n−1.$

Comment: The pattern is obvious here. But how to put it in terms of m and n?

Comment: good guess, I checked the numbers for m=1,...,20 and they match.

Comment: did you already find the pattern for the polinomials in the exponent of a?

Comment: @miracle173 yes, in comments under the original post, the polynomial for $a$ is the polynomial for $b$ coming from $m+1$ and $n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

**I Found**

$$f(a^n\cdot b^m) = a^{{(2^{m})}{(m-1)}} \cdot b^{{(2^{m-2})}{(m+1)}} \cdot 
\prod _{j=1} ^{m} \prod _{i=1} ^{n-1} f(a^i\cdot b^{j})^{2^{m-j}}$$

Comment: I calculated `g(u,v):=[2^v,2^((v-2)*(v+1))]+2^v*sum(sum(e[i,v-j],i,1,u-1),j,1,v);`, where g(u,v) is your function (the exponents) and e(u,x) is my function and got g(2,2)=[12,5], which means $a^{12}b^5$. but my function calculates e([2,2])=[8,8]. So I think there is an error in your formula.

Comment: `g(u,v):=[2^v,2^((v-2)*(v+1))]+sum(sum(2^(v-j)*e[i,j],i,1,u-1),j,1,v)` sorry, but I get g(2,2)=[8,6] now.

Comment: But g (2,2)= a^4 . b^3 . g (1,1)^2 . g (1,2) = (8,8)

Comment: $b^{2^{(m-2)(m+1)}} =b^{2^0}=b$ if m=2

Comment: `g(u,v):=[2^v,2^(v-2)*(v+1)]+sum(sum(2^(v-j)*e[i,j],i,1,u-1),j,1,v)` gives g(3,4)=[192,252] but e[3,4]=[208,252], but the exponent of b seens to be correct now. It also works for higher number

Comment: Now it's correct. Sorry Miracle173 for disturbing you for long. Actually I am now studying for exams so can't concentrate on this fully.

Answer (score 0):

So, the friend who originally came up with this question also came up with a solution for it.

$$f(a^mb^n)=a^{[F(m-1,n)]}\times{b^{[F(m,n-1)]}}$$

where

$$F(m,n)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{min(m,n)}{2^{m+n-i}\times{(-1)^i}\times{\frac{(m+n-i)!}{(m-i)!(n-i)!i!}}}$$

Note: $[X]$ is smallest integer larger than $X$.

I believe the above is a correct answer to part (b) of the question. Now only an answer to the final part (which was not part of the original question) is needed, which is to find a general formula for $f(n)$ where $n$ is any natural number.