# Property of a recursive integer sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, recursion

Loosely related to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295019/closed-sum-free-form-for-the-n-th-derivative-of-operatornamearcsinh-frac), I encountered a recursive sequence of integers $(b(j,n))_{j\in\mathbb Z,n\in\mathbb N}$ given by

$$
 b(0,1)=-1\qquad b(j,n)=0\text{ if }j<0\text{ or }j\geq n\\
 b(j,n+1)=b(j,n)(2j-n)+b(j-1,n)(2j-3n-1)\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb N, j\in\lbrace 0,\ldots,n\rbrace.\tag{1}
$$

Note that the non-vanishing terms of $(b(j,n))_{j\in\mathbb Z,n\in\mathbb N}$ form a triangle
$$
\begin{matrix}
&\underline{j=0}&\underline{j=1}&\ldots&&\\
n=1\,|&-1 &&&&\\
n=2\,|&\hphantom{-}1 &\hphantom{-}2&&&\\
\vdots&-2 &-5&-6&&\\
&\hphantom{-}6 &\hphantom{-}21 &\hphantom{-}24 &\hphantom{-}24&\\
&-24 &-108 &-189 &-120 &-120
\end{matrix}
$$

Now explicit calculations suggest that one can attach polynomial weights in $j$ and $n$ to the $b(j,n)$ such that the **sum over any row vanishes**. More precisely:

> **Conjecture.** For any $n\in\mathbb N$
>   $$
> \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} b(j,n)\big( 32j^3-32(2n-1)j^2 +2(22n^2-30n+13)j-(n-1)(2n-1)(5n-6) \big)=0
> $$

I believe this to be true, but so far I was not able to prove it. The problem with induction here is that when using (1) in the induction step, the weight gets $j^4$-terms which then can't be directly connected to (2) anymore.

The obvious way would be trying to find a closed form for the $b(j,n)$ but that seems quite difficult and I was hoping there would be an easier, "intrinsic" (only using the recursion or other properties of the sequence) way of proving this. I'm aware of the [generating functions ansatz](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/271036/495075) but as the "weights" in (1) depend on $j,n$ this seems to not work directly either.

Thanks in advance for any answer or comment!

---

*Edit:* just to vizualize the problem, the first non-vanishing elements of the sequence in question $\scriptstyle\big(b(j,n)(32j^3-32(2n-1)j^2 +2(22n^2-30n+13)j-(n-1)(2n-1)(5n-6))\big)_{j\in\mathbb Z,n\in\mathbb N}$ are given by

$$
\begin{matrix}
&\underline{j=0}&\underline{j=1}&\ldots&&\\
n=1\,|&0 &&&&\\
n=2\,|&-12&\hphantom{-}12&&&\\
\vdots&\hphantom{-}180 &-120& -60&&\\
&-1764 &\hphantom{-}84 &\hphantom{-}1104 &\hphantom{-}576&\\
&\hphantom{-}16416 &\hphantom{-}12312 &-13608 &-7920 &-7200
\end{matrix}
$$

Now it is evident that any row here sums up to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some partial results. I reduce your conjecture to identities involving only polynomials, which are hopefully easier to show.

Observing the rightmost part of the triangle, it seems that $b(n-1,n)=(-1)^n (n!)$, and indeed this fact is easily checked by induction on $n$. Going leftwards by just one step, it also seems that $b(n-2,n)=(-1)^{n-1}n!\frac{(n-1)(n-8)}{12}$, and indeed this fact is also easily checked by induction on $n$. More generally, let us define for integers $0\leq d \lt n$

$$
t(d,n)=\frac{b(n-1-d,n)}{(-1)^{n+d}n!\prod_{k=1}^d (n-k)} \tag{3}
$$

So, the two remarks above tell us that $t(0,n)=1$ and $t(1,n)=\frac{n-8}{12}$. In fact,  I have checked for $n\leq 10$ the following :

**Conjecture 2.** When nonzero (i.e. for $n \gt d$), $t(d,n)$ is a polynomial of degree $d$ in $n$.

When translated in terms of $t$, the recursive relation governing $b$ becomes

$$
n(n+1)t(d+1,n+1)-(n-d-1)(n+2d+3)t(d+1,n)=(n-2d-2)t(d,n) \tag{4}
$$

Let $h(j,n)= 32j^3-32(2n-1)j^2 +2(22n^2-30n+13)j-(n-1)(2n-1)(5n-6)$. Your sum $S_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} b(j,n)h(j,n)$  can be rewritten as $S_n=\sum_{d=0}^{n-1} h(n-1-d,n)b(n-1-d,n)=(-1)^n n!U_{n}(n)$ where $U_{n}(m)=\sum_{d=0}^{n-1} (-1)^d h(m-1-d,m)t(d,m)\prod_{k=1}^d (m-k)$. Now, I have checked for $n\leq 10$ the following

**Conjecture 3.** $U_{n}$ is a polynomial (in $m$) divisible by $\prod_{k=1}^{n} (m-k)$.

In particular, we have $U_{n}(n)=0$, which implies your conjecture.

Comment: Very interesting approach! I haven't thought of structuring the sequence diagonally before but this looks like it could work out somehow. I'll try to follow this idea for now, thank you; *if* you're still interested in and/or working on this problem, feel free to share anything regarding it!

Comment: Just as an update: I was able to prove Conjecture 2, but Conjecture 3 seems to be a bit trickier. Any progress or further ideas on it?

Comment: @FrederikvomEnde If I remember correctly, an approach which looks promising is to look for "low-degree" linear dependence relations between the $t_k$ polynomials. By low-degree, I mean that the coefficients are polynomial in $n$ with small degree ($\leq 2$, in fact). So your initial conjecture is a low-degree relation between $b$'s in  the same row. If I remember correctly, again, there is a relation of the form $\sum_{i<r}{c_it_i}+t_r=0$ where all the $c_i$ have degree $1$, except one of them which has degree $2$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't use generating functions (although a huge mess).

Let $F = \sum_{j,n}b(j,n)x^jy^n$ be the generating function.

The recurrence relation becomes a PDE:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(2yx + 2yx^2) - \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(y^2 - 3xy^2) = F(1+yx)$$

Assuming this, you have to prove the following (heavily simplified but still horrendous):

$$[32\frac{\partial^3 F}{\partial x^3} -64y\frac{\partial^3 F}{\partial x^2 \partial y} + 44y^2\frac{\partial^3 F}{\partial x \partial y^2} - 10y^3\frac{\partial^3 F}{\partial y^3} + $$

$$+ 128\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} -80y\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x \partial y} -57y^2\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2} + $$

$$+ 90\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} -14y\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} - 6F]\vert_{x = 1} = 0$$

Which we get by encoding the goal as a PDE, then setting $x=1$ which sums the coefficients along each power of $y$, and saying it must equal $0$.

I'm sure a computer could do the rest.

Comment: As I see it, there are two problems. 1. I believe that in the first PDE you missed a term $-y$ which comes from the initial condition $b(0,1)=-1$ as the recursive def. of the $b(j,n)$ only kicks in if $n>1$. This complicates the search for an analytical solution in Mathematica a lot. 2. There are some convergence problems arising. The solution of the PDE as you named it needs a boundary condition to be fully determined. However, $F(0,y)$ is of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b(0,n)y^n$ where $b(0,n)=(-1)^n(n-1)!$ so the series has convergence radius 0 and we can't specify any boundary condition.

Comment: (2/2) The latter to me also seems to be a problem as for the conjecture we have to evaluate the function at $x=1$ and arbitrary $y$, but it looks like it doesn't even converge there (if $y\neq 0$ of course) (?)

Comment: I didn't try this one but in cases where sequences grow fast, especially involving factorials, exponential g.f. come handy.