# Solving recurrence relation in 2 variables plus constant

Tags: recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

I've encountered [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206158/solving-recurrence-relation-in-2-variables) question, asking to solve the recurrence
$$F(n,m) = F(n-1,m) + F(n,m-1)$$
for some initial conditions. I wonder how the solution would change if we add a constant, say

$ G(n,m) = G(n-1,m) + G(n,m-1)+2$.

One answer for the [mentioned post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206158/solving-recurrence-relation-in-2-variables) suggested generating functions. What would change here? For simplicity, let's assume $G(1,m) = m − 1$ and $G(n, 1) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $H(n,m)=G(n,m)+2$, then $$\begin{aligned} H(n,m)&=G(n,m)+2 \\ &=G(n-1,m)+G(n,m-1)+4 \\&=(G(n-1,m)+2)+(G(n,m-1)+2) \\&=H(n-1,m)+H(n,m-1) \end{aligned}$$
You can now solve the recurrence for $H$ and deduce the recurrence for $G$ by writing $G(n,m)=H(n,m)-2$.

Comment: Thanks, nice trick! I'm afraid I cannot extract $H$ from the resulting equation though.

Comment: It is the one you talked about in your question that can be solved using generating functions. A lot of calculus though !

Comment: Yeah, tried to use the method vonbrand gave in that post, but it's non-trivial to find an analytic solution. Will spend some time on it... Thanks again!