# Under what circumstances multi variable recurrences are solvable?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Somewhat similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206158/solving-recurrence-relation-in-2-variables), but more general:

- Under what circumstances there exists a solution for recurrences with *more* than one variable?

Suppose that my recurrence satisfies the following syntax:
$$
T(a,b) = T(t,t) + T(t,t) + c
$$
with initial conditions:
$$
T(0,b)=b~|~1~|~0 \\
T(a,0)=a~|~1~|~0
$$
where
$$
t ::= v+v~|~v-v     \\
v ::= a~|~b~|~0~|~1 \\
c ::= 1~|~2~|~3
$$
Here are a few recurrences to demonstrate what I mean:
$$
(1)~~~~~T(a,b)=T(a-1,b-1)+T(a-1,b)+1
$$
$$
(2)~~~~~T(a,b)=T(b,b-1)+T(a-1,b)+1
$$
$$
(3)~~~~~T(a,b)=T(a-1,b)+T(a-1,b)+1
$$
Is there any algorithm that provides a closed form for $T$?

Comment: The notation is obscure, please rewrite it in a more conventional form. Does every value depend only on diagonal values? And what is the problem with applying generating functions if the recurrence is linear?

Comment: Here is a link to general theory, [Linear recurrences with constant coefficients: the multivariate case](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X00001473).

Comment: @Conifold I couldn't extract the answer from that paper ... It looks like even with this restricted grammar the answer is no, right?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your grammar.

Comment: @Conifold I added three examples - do they help?

Comment: Yes, much better. Are you saying that their methods can not solve such recurrences? Did you try to find the general solution first (without $+1$)?

Comment: I actually didn't understand their method -- I thought they were building some kind of family of counter-examples that proved these recurrences don't have a polynomial / exp / binomial solution ... without the `+1` everything shrinks to `0`'s ...

Comment: Exactly as the linked post says, make a (bivariate) generating function, turn the recursion into a functional equation/algebraic equation/DE, solve that thing, extract coefficients. Your +1's will only add some geometric series terms to the equations, which shouldn't change things materially. That should make intuitive sense since you could just track the number of +1's needed. in terms of $a$ and $b$. What difficulties do you have with performing these standard manipulations? (Your grammar notation is indeed deeply confusing. You also don't mean $T(0, b) = v$ since you allowed $v=a$, say.)

Comment: Fixed $T(a,0)$ and $T(0,b)$ syntax