# Solving recurrence with 2 variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am about to solve the recurrence

$a(n,m)=\frac{1}{2}a(n,m-1)+\frac{1}{2}a(n-1,m)$ with boundary conditions $a(0,m)=(\frac{1}{2})^m, \forall m\in\mathbb N$ and $a(n,0)=(\frac{1}{2})^n, \forall n\in\mathbb N$
where $a:\mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb R$.

My questions are

1. For this specific problem, I found the solution $a(n,m)=(1/2)^{n+m}\binom{n+m}{n}$ using graphics (see [my sketch here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe15e.jpg)). Is there an algebraic way to solve this problem?
2. For "1D" linear constant-coefficient difference equation, we know that a geometric sequence with proper base is a fundamental solution to the difference equation. Can we generalise this notion to "2D difference equations"?
3. Is there a closed-form general solution to the "2D difference equation" without boundary condition?

** Side note **

I found this problem as I was analysing a simplified Swiss tournament model. $a(n,m)$ represents the portion of teams which won $n$ games and lost $m$ games after $n+m$ games.

Comment: Could you show us your work?

Comment: You can checkout my sketch at https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe15e.jpg

Answer (score 3):

We can get rid of the coefficients by setting

$$
b(n, m) = 2^{n+m}a(n, m)
$$

for all $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$, giving us the recurrence

$$
b(n, m) = b(n, m - 1) + b(n - 1, m).
$$

(Adding this factor is not just motivated by our prior knowledge of the solution, it's a standard method when solving recurrence relations in one variable.) In this form it has already been solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/271036/965232), where they use generating functions in two variables. I believe they also answer some of your other questions there.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

We can use the characteristic function technique. From

$$a(n,m)=\frac{1}{2}a(n,m-1)+\frac{1}{2}a(n-1,m)$$

after multiplication by $x^ny^m$ we have

$$
a(n,m)x^n y^m-\frac{1}{2}a(n,m-1)x^n y^m-\frac{1}{2}a(n-1,m)x^n y^m
$$

and summing up

$$
S(x,y) -\frac y2 S(x,y)-\frac x2 S(x,y) = \phi_0(x,y)
$$

or

$$
S(x,y) = \frac{\phi_0(x,y)}{1-\frac 12(x+y)}
$$

Here $\phi_0(x,y)=\sum_k\left(\frac x2\right)^k + \sum_j\left(\frac x2\right)^j$. Now calling $u = \frac x2, u = \frac y2$ we follow with

$$
Z(u,v) = \frac{\sum_k u^k + \sum_j v^j}{1-(u+v)}
$$

or

$$
Z(u,v) = \sum_i\left(u+v\right)^i\left(\sum_k u^k + \sum_j v^j\right) 
$$

so the polynomial $Z(u,v)=\sum_n\sum_m b(n,m)u^nv^m$ coefficients are related to $a(n,m)$

Comment: Could you please explain how $S(x,y)$ is defined? @Cesareo

Comment: $S(x,y) = \sum_n\sum_m a(n,m)x^n y^m$